# There exist $\mathcal{C}^0$ parameterizations for $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ curves?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ curve. Assume it has a $\mathcal{C}^1$ regular parameterization. Could it have a $\mathcal{C}^0$ parameterization?

I think no, since any parameterization is of the form
$$
\Gamma(s)=\gamma (h(s))
$$

where $h: I' \to I$ is a diffemorphism. Since $h$ is at least $\mathcal{C}^1$, then we necessarily have that any parameterization is at least $\mathcal{C}^1$. Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $t \mapsto t^{1/3}$ is a $C^0$-parameterization of the real line, which is not a $C^1$-parameterization.